# Lowercase in xml element names when using MvcContrib's XmlResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, mvccontrib

I've got a class like this

```
public class Reply
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I use it as a param to XmlResult constructor, I get an output where xml element names first letters are uppercase. But I need them to be plain lowercase. Perhaps there is some sort of attribute which I miss? Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation on XmlResult.

Comment: You can always go directly to the MVCContrib Source: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d389f80f5be2#src%2fMVCContrib%2fActionResults%2fXmlResult.cs

Comment: The XMLElement attribute has an ElementName argument, you might want to try that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For serializing you add either:

```
[XmlElement("loweredname")]
```

or

```
[XmlAttribute("loweredname")]
```

for XML Elements and Attributes respectively. Hopefully this works for what you need.

**Update:** Your class should be something like:

```
[XmlRoot("reply")]
public class Reply
{
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I thought it should be. However, I still cannot apply XmlElement to the whole class, so I get <Reply> instead of <reply>. Do I need to sort of create some wrapper that will hold Reply as its property, and set XmlElement there?

Comment: Use [XmlRoot("loweredname")] for the class

Comment: @HiveHicks or `XmlType("loweredname")` if it's not actually the root